# ASP.NET Core MVC Label Tag Helper

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, label

I am building my web razor view and have an issue with the Label Tag Helper.

This is my markup:

```
<label asp-for="customer.FirstName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
```

The problem is the First and Name are being show on separate lines and I want them on one line. Apologies if this is a simple question; I am a novice at this.

Many thanks for any help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play with column size(class properties) eg :

```
<label asp-for="customer.FirstName" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">First Name</label>
```

It may be useful for you to get along with how the **Grid System** of bootstrap works:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
and
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/bootstrap-for-beginners-part-threebootstrap-grids/

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply / answer. I do sort of know about the Grid System in that you can set any div container to take up to 12 segments and that you can specify different numbers for different sized / devices. Not fully there yet though. Thanks again.

Comment: Can I just ask a question on that so I fully understand your answer. What is the label defaulting to? I am running it on a large desktop screen. Thanks.

Comment: Its pretty simple. Look at Bootstrap Grid System from the second link. By adding to colum 4 instead of 2 we expanded the column so two words could fit within one row.

Comment: Thank you. it's making much more sense now.